# sed s command pattern matching for 0 or 1 match

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to use `sed`, `s` (substitution) command to replace some strings with `REPLACEMENT`.

I'd like to use 1 pattern matching to capture both scenarios, which are basically
 `something` or `something#otherString`

below, is what I imagined should work, but it does not.

```
s|${some-not-interested-Variable}/someString/someOtherString/x.y(#x.y)?|REPLACEMENT|ig;
```

below is what worked. but i do not like the duplication.

```
s|${some-not-interested-Variable}/someString/someOtherString/x.y#x.y|REPLACEMENT|ig;
s|${some-not-interested-Variable}/someString/someOtherString/x.y|REPLACEMENT|ig;
```

note, I used `|` as the delimiter.

Can you please help me why my 1st one is not working?

Comment: The metacharacter `?` matches zero or one times, used in conjunction with grouping will most likely solve your problem e.g  to match `ab` or `abxy` and replace by X use `sed 's/ab\(xy\)\?/X/' file`

Comment: did you enable extended pattern matching?

Comment: How do I enable extended the time extended pattern matching ? @paul Hodges?

Comment: @potong that is basically what I did. but I did not scape the brackets in the example I wrote.  During testing, I think I even tried to escape them , I will give it another try.  I definitely did not escape question mark. I thought they are all meta characters in the pattern matching, so no need to escape , it already has special meaning

Comment: @Minnie if you invoke extended pattern matching then `sed -E 's/ab(xy)?/X/' file` is the same as my first comment.

Comment: Thank you very much both. I have done some research based on your help. And I think it should work, once I get to use/test it on my code.   https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Command_002dLine-Options.html#index-Extended-regular-expressions_002c-choosing

Comment: @potong i can confirm the escape one definitive worked for me. and i prefer this way as my strings has too many characters which would have special meaning if i use '-E' or '-r'.